# Turing machine with one state that converts binary to decimal

Tags: computer-science, computation-theory, turing-machines, computer-science-theory

I heard that a Turing machine with one state should be able to convert binary numbers into decimal numbers. I am trying to figure out how that would be possible. I'm currently quite unsuccessfully brute-forcing my way to a result. How would one synthesise that in more elegant way?

The binary number is given in reversed order eg. 25 is 10011 not 11001. I would argue this makes it easier. Not sure if it also is a necessity. The number is encapsulated at the ends by two other symbols. Additionally 0 and 1 are in the beginning denoted as T and F --> .......TFFTTXXXXX. The resulting decimal number should look like this: .....25-----XXXXX. Also, the halt state is not counted as real state. To my understanding this is a necessity to formulate a problem like that.

Researching one-state Turing machines I found [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1901.07125.pdf). I see that there is somewhat a carry and a counter bit, but I can not explain myself how this will help to increase a decimal number up to 10 and then do the carry to the next bit. Given one state I am thinking about at least 10 different terms for each decimal digit and a few more symbols for breaks, carry, counters etc.. Therefore, the definition of my single state gets quite long. Here an example to illustrate what I mean (obvioulsy wrong):

```
state trigger --> (output, state, shift): 
s, 1 --> (2,s,>) 
s, 2 --> (3,s,>) 
..., s, 
s, 8 --> (9,s,>)
s, 9 --> (c,s,>)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With only one state, you *must* encode information in counting bits. The trick is that you count down on the binary number and count up on the decimal number.

Say we start as `......[T]FFTTXXXXX`, per your example, with `[]` denoting our current head position after a write. Go to the right and flip the `T` with an `F` in order to decrease the binary. Then, overwrite the encountered (and any future) `.` with a `1`. You should now have the following:

- `.....[.]FFFTTXXXXX`
- `.....[1]FFFTTXXXXX`

Go back to the right. Now, we run into a problem: We need to go past the `F`s, flip them to `T`s, go to the first `T` and then back. In order to not flip the digits we just passed, we replace them by a placeholder like `-`, resulting in the following sequence:

- `.....1[F]FFTTXXXXX`
- `.....1-[F]FTTXXXXX`
- `.....1--[F]TTXXXXX`
- `.....1---[T]TXXXXX`
- `.....1--[-]FTXXXXX`

Now, go back and replace the placeholder:

- `.....1-[-]TFTXXXXX`
- `.....1[-]TTFTXXXXX`
- `.....[1]TTTFTXXXXX`

And now just increment the `1` to a `2`: `.....2[T]TTFTXXXXX`.

Go to the right again and repeat this process:

- `.....[2]FTTFTXXXXX`
- `.....3[F]TTFTXXXXX`
- `.....3-[T]TFTXXXXX`
- `.....3[-]FTFTXXXXX`
- `.....[3]TFTFTXXXXX`
- `.....4[T]FTFTXXXXX`
- etc. until the turing machine halts at the first `X` encountered

The only issue you will encounter is that you'll need to override a decimal `9` with a `10` somehow. Do this by replacing the `9` with a placeholder, going to the left, running the normal state transition from a `.` to a `1`, going back right and replacing the placeholder with a `0`. Don't forget to add a transition from `0` to `1` as well.

---

By the way, this seems like a homework assignment of a certain lecture I attend as well ;)

Comment: Thank you very much! This was well explained and shows me that it is indeed possible to do it with one single state. May I ask how you came up with this? Is there like a pattern for this or did you just think really hard?

Comment: @Mr.Sh4nnon my lecture's homework discussion livestream mentioned the key principle of "count down the decimal, count up the binary". The rest was thinking about it at 2am :)

Comment: hahah I spent way too much time on the first turing machine exercise and did not have the will power to just think about it till 2 o‘clock :)

Comment: @Mr.Sh4nnon relatable, that's why I googled the problem, just to arrive at this very SO question :D

Comment: And even answered it after you solved it, thanks! I owe you one xD I found almost no results about one state turing machines. Except for one paper that did not help much. I hope it will be explained how tasks like this can be solved more systematically.